# Calculate value of k such that $f^k \le \epsilon$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

> Show that $(\frac{y-1}{y+1})^k\le \epsilon$, $0 \lt \epsilon \lt 1$, $y \ge 1,$ if $k \ge -\frac{1}{2}log(\epsilon)y$.

My idea is to derive the second inequality from the first.

taking $\log()$ on both sides, yields $k \log(\frac{y-1}{y+1}) \le \log (\epsilon)$ $\implies k \ge \frac{\log (\epsilon)}{log(\frac{y-1}{y+1})}$
because this estimate is the sharpest you can get. Unfortunaly, I dont the a way to conclude above.

Hints are appreciated.
Greetings.

Comment: Do you know anything useful about log(1+x), particularly for small x? Can you rearrange the fraction with y in it to look like 1+a potentially small thing?

Comment: $\log(1+x) \approx x$ , $\frac{y-1}{y+1} = 1- \frac{2}{y+1} $ do you mean something like that?

Comment: Something like that indeed. See if you can show that in the range of interest the approximate equality is in fact a more useful inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't attempt to derive the second inequality from the first, given that you are required to do precisely the opposite! Continuing from where you stopped, you want to show that

$$k \ge -\frac y 2 \log \epsilon \implies k \ge \frac {\log \epsilon} {\log \dfrac {y-1} {y+1}}$$

and it is sufficient (but not necessary) to show that

$$-\frac y 2 \log \epsilon \ge \frac {\log \epsilon} {\log \dfrac {y-1} {y+1}}$$

or, equivalently,

$$\log \frac {y+1} {y-1} \ge \frac 2 y .$$

Consider the map $f : (1, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(y) = \log \dfrac {y+1} {y-1} - \dfrac 2 y$. We want to show that $f \ge 0$.

We have

$$f' (y) = \frac {y-1} {y+1} \frac {(y-1) - (y+1)} {(y-1)^2} + \frac 2 {y^2} = \frac {-2} {(y-1)(y+1)} + \frac 2 {y^2} = \frac {-2} {y^2(y-1)(y+1)} \le 0$$

which shows that $f$ is decreasing on $(1, \infty)$, so that $f(y) \ge \lim \limits _{y \to \infty} f(y) = 0$, which is exactly what we wanted.

The above establishes the desired inequality for $y>1$. It is easy to check it by hand for $y=1$, whence it will hold true for $y \ge 1$ as desired.